# Is there a specific format of storing environment variables in .bash_profile?

Tags: python-3.x, bash, macos, atom-editor, slack-api

Following is the python code I am using to send messages to slack. The following code throws an error when I try to get the api_key from environment, but it works perfectly fine when I replace `webhook` with the actual API key.

```
import requests
import json
import os

data = {
    "text" : "hi there"
}

webhook = os.environ.get("SLACK_API_KEY")
requests.post(webhook, json.dumps(data))
```

The **SLACK_API_KEY** is an environment variable which I have stored in **.bash_profile** folder of my system. The API key has the following format:
`https://hooks.slack.com/services/alpha_numeric/alpha_numeric/alpha_numeric`

This is how I have stored the API key in my .bash_profile folder:

```
export SLACK_API_KEY="https://hooks.slack.com/services/alpha_numeric/alpha_numeric/alpha_numeric"
```

This is the error when I try to export the api_key from environment.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nikhilsawal/OneDrive/investment_portfolio/helper_functions.py", line 10, in <module>
    requests.post(webhook, json.dumps(data))
  File "/Users/nikhilsawal/OneDrive/investment_portfolio/track_proj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 119, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/nikhilsawal/OneDrive/investment_portfolio/track_proj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/nikhilsawal/OneDrive/investment_portfolio/track_proj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 516, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/Users/nikhilsawal/OneDrive/investment_portfolio/track_proj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 449, in prepare_request
    p.prepare(
  File "/Users/nikhilsawal/OneDrive/investment_portfolio/track_proj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 314, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
  File "/Users/nikhilsawal/OneDrive/investment_portfolio/track_proj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 388, in prepare_url
    raise MissingSchema(error)
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'None': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://None?
[Finished in 0.149s]
```

Comment: Have you restarted your session so that the shell rereads its profile?

Comment: Yes I did try that!

Comment: Based on the tag, it sounds like you are running the script from inside Atom. Are you actually starting Atom from your login shell? If not, it's not inheriting from the evironment where `SLACK_API_KEY` is set.

Comment: @chepner I tried running the script directly from Atom as well as from shell. In either cases it throws the same error. And yes I am assuming that is the problem, its not inheriting from the environment. Do I need to add a path to the directory where the script is saved in the .bash_profile folder? Something like ```export PATH="/Users/nikhilsawal/OneDrive/investment_portfolio/:${PATH}"```

Comment: No, you need to arrange for Atom to be a subprocess (or descendent) of your shell, or you need to find a way to set the environment variable in Atom's environment itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your env var is it stored correctly, to check your environment variable you could do :`echo $SLACK_API_KEY` in your shell or you could do `env` and grep after it.

Pay attention that `~/.bash_profile` if for user-specific settings and actions (login shells only)  alternatively there is  `.bashrc` which is executed for interactive non-login shells.

I suggest to put your variable in `~/.profile` and then don't forget to `source ~/.profile` or wherever you decide to place you env variable .

If they do not exists you can create them, I recommend this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45684/what-is-the-difference-between-profile-and-bash-profile#:%7E:text=profile%20is%20for%20things%20that,or%20shells%20executed%20at%20login.) which explains the differences.

Also you can set the var it directly from the script:

`os.environ["SLACK_API_KEY"] = "value"`

Did a small test with `~/.bash_profile` for your case:
[image]

Comment: My understanding is that .profile is intended for POSIX shells, so you'll have to write: `VAR=value; export VAR`

Comment: @dejdej I tried echoing the variable from shell, but for some reason it does not show up. Also I don't see ```.bashrc``` and ```.profile``` in my root directory. Do I need to add them separately? I can't put the key inside the script since I am pushing it to github. Do you suggest having a separate script that I shouldn't be tracking?

Comment: problem solved! I didn't ```source .bash_profile``` after making the changes Thank you @dejdej! Thank you guys appreciate it. Also I was missing the ```;```. Thank you @glenn for pointing that out. Thank you @choroba and @chepner!

Comment: one file is .bash_profile.  You have to show hidden files to see files that begin with a dot.